# What would the break DC for a rope made of a shirt be?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

One of my friends had his players tie up an NPC's hands and legs by having the barbarian and wizard remove their shirts and use it as improvised rope, but he is not sure how hard it would be for the NPC with a Strength of 12 to rip the clothes and make a run for it.

My question is: what is the Strength DC to rip open the bindings made of a cloth shirt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**13 (Easy)**

From the "Damaging Objects" page, we learn that

- Rope, paper, and cloth all have 0 hardness and 2 HP per inch of thickness
- 1 inch diameter rope has a break DC of 23

In your scenario, I see two advantages for the rope.

- It is corded (has many different strings woven together)
- It is thicker (Taking a shirt and making a rope won't get you a solid inch of material)

Since it's not corded, someone being held could rip apart one section at a time (tearing clothes isn't particularly hard), especially if they can get their teeth to it.  I would give it a 13, or the same difficulty as breaking down a simple door.

Better advise them not to leave the captive alone!